# Rake Aborted: Wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, rake

I was trying to integrate twitter authentication into my Ruby on Rails application (from the Ruby on Rails Tutorial).

As a result I dropped a table (user table ) and had to recreate it. I want to now populate the database and I have this code for populating the table

```
namespace :db do
  desc "Fill database with sample data"
  task populate: :environment do
    User.create!(name: "Example User",
                 email: "example@railstutorial.org",
                 password: "foobar",
                 password_confirmation: "foobar")
    99.times do |n|
      name  = Faker::Name.name
      email = "example-#{n+1}@railstutorial.org"
      password  = "password"
      User.create!(name: name,
                   email: email,
                   password: password,
                   password_confirmation: password)
    end
  end
end
```

The following commands work:

```
$bundle exec rake:db migrate
$bundle exec rake:db reset
```

However the $bundle exec rake:db populate does NOT work.

There are the errors I am getting:

```
    $ bundle exec rake db:populate --trace
    ** Invoke db:populate (first_time)
    ** Invoke environment (first_time)
    ** Execute environment
    ** Execute db:populate
    rake aborted!
    wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-2.0.4/lib/devise/models/database_auth
    enticatable.rb:105:in `password_digest'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.2.0/lib/active_model/errors.rb
    :254:in `block in add_on_blank'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.2.0/lib/active_model/errors.rb
    :253:in `each'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.2.0/lib/active_model/errors.rb
    :253:in `add_on_blank'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.2.0/lib/active_model/validatio
    ns/presence.rb:9:in `validate'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/callb
    acks.rb:310:in `_callback_before_39'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/callb
    acks.rb:484:in `_run__584816360__validate__204154762__callbacks'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/callb
    acks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/callb
    acks.rb:385:in `_run_validate_callbacks'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/callb
    acks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.2.0/lib/active_model/validatio
    ns.rb:212:in `run_validations!'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.2.0/lib/active_model/validatio
    ns/callbacks.rb:53:in `block in run_validations!'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/callb
    acks.rb:425:in `_run__584816360__validation__204154762__callbacks'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/callb
    acks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/callb
    acks.rb:385:in `_run_validation_callbacks'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/callb
    acks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.2.0/lib/active_model/validatio
    ns/callbacks.rb:53:in `run_validations!'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.2.0/lib/active_model/validatio
    ns.rb:179:in `valid?'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/validat
    ions.rb:69:in `valid?'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/validat
    ions.rb:77:in `perform_validations'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/validat
    ions.rb:56:in `save!'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/attribu
    te_methods/dirty.rb:33:in `save!'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/transac
    tions.rb:246:in `block in save!'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/transac
    tions.rb:295:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/connect
    ion_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:190:in `transaction'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/transac
    tions.rb:208:in `transaction'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/transac
    tions.rb:293:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/transac
    tions.rb:246:in `save!'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/validat
    ions.rb:41:in `create!'
    c:/tuffy/shopgodt/lib/tasks/sample_data.rake:4:in `block (2 levels) in <top (req
    uired)>'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_lev
    el'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handlin
    g'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handlin
    g'
    c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
    c:/Ruby193/bin/rake:32:in `<main>'
    Tasks: TOP => db:populate
```

Any help on this matter is appreciated. Thanks again!

============================================================

Update 05/02/2012: Since I had wanted to add third party logins (facebook,twitter) I added the Devise gem but I am not sure which command I ran that resulted in these these two lines that were added to my app/models/User.rb file

```
:token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
 devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
```

Once I commented them out everything ran fine. I would like to understand though what these two lines are doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two hints to what's wrong

`c:/tuffy/shopgodt/lib/tasks/sample_data.rake:4:in 'block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'`

tells you it's on line 4 which is the call to `create!`

Coupled with

`c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.2.0/lib/active_model/validations/presence.rb:9:in 'validate'`

says that a validation is failing. Is there a validation expecting the presence of some field you're not providing? Check your `User` model for `validates :some_field_name, :presence => true`

Comment: Hi @TCopple thanks for responding!
My Users table has the following fields: ID, email, created_at, updated_at, password_digest, remember_token, admin.
Code in Users model :
  `it { should respond_to(:name) }
  it { should respond_to(:email) }
  it { should respond_to(:password_digest) }
  it { should respond_to(:password) }
  it { should respond_to(:authenticate) }
  it { should respond_to(:password_confirmation) }
  it { should respond_to(:remember_token) }
  it { should respond_to(:admin) }
  it { should respond_to(:authenticate) }  
  it { should be_valid }
  it { should_not be_admin }`

Comment: Two things. 1) When adding information please put the code in the original post so everyone knows it's there. 2) Those look like test cases for the `User` model not the actual model itself. Post the contents of `app/models/user.rb`

Comment: Hi TCopple I just realised I pasted the wrong code sorry! I had added Devise and I am not sure which command line I ran but my User model had two additional lines . I am pasting them to the original post.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it could be something on the `User` class itself. Possibly in the validation.

Have you got any custom validation in there or any other custom callbacks? It would be worth checking those.

You could do the `User.create!` independently of the rake task in the console to confirm if that is the problem.

Comment: Hi Shadwell... I did try to create a user via the webpage and it gave me the same error.

Answer (score 2):

OK - I was having the same issues. I just finished up with the same tutorial and have spent the past 3 hrs pulling my hair out. Going through the Gem's code and everything made me realize what was up.

What's going on is this:

In ch.6 the tutorial asks you to add in `'has_secure_password'` to your user model. Strip this helper out of any model you're using with Devise. While Devise does not explicitly call that helper in the Gem, it's code pretty much mimics what 'has_secure_password' does.

After you do that, kill your server, rails console, etc. Start over and life should be happy once again.